# Creating Multiple Different objects in Driver.class

Tags: java

I'm trying to create 3 different house objects with different parameters in java (houseName, houseAge) in my driver.class, but can't seem to figure out how. I just started learning to code, and I've been banging my head against the wall for hours on this one. I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't seem to get it. Thanks in advance!

Driver.class:

```
public class HouseDriver {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
  House house1 = new House();
  }
}
```

House.class:

```
public class House {
  private String houseName;
  private int houseAge;
   
  public House (String houseName, int houseAge) {
    houseName = nameIn;
    houseAge = ageIn;
  }
  public String getName() {
  return houseName;
  }
  public int getAge() {
  return ageIn;
  }
  public void setName (String houseName) {
  houseName = nameIn;
  }
}
```

Error: HouseDriver.java:3: error: constructor House in class House cannot be applied to given types;
House house1 = new House();
^
required: String,int
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

Answer (score 1):

When you create a constructor with parameters in Java, the compiler won't automatically generate a no-argument constructor.That's why you won't be able to create an object like this. To create instances of the class without passing constructor arguments, you must explicitly define a no-argument constructor.

```
public House() {

  }
```

Apart from that, the argument constructor method's variable assignments should be done using this like this:

```
public House(String nameIn, int ageIn) {
  this.houseName = nameIn;
  this.houseAge = ageIn;
}
```

The use of `this` in the constructor is used to distinguish between the instance variables and the constructor parameters when they have the same names.

Comment: The `this.` is only required of the instance variable names are being shadowed by arguments or local variables of the same name, which is common in constructors but is not present in your example. Otherwise, great answer!

Comment: Additionally, the _default constructor_ is only implied when a class has no _constructor method_ definitions.

Answer (score 0):

House constructor requires 2 arguments but you are using no arguments when executing new House(). Add house name and age inside the parentheses.

Answer (score -1):

```
        import java.util.Scanner; //added
                
        public class HouseDriver {
            
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                
                //to input values use Scanner 
                Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in); //added
                
                System.out.println("Enter House Name: "); //added
                String housename=input.next();
                
                System.out.println("Enter House Age: "); //added
                int houseage=input.nextInt();
                
                House house1 = new House(housename,houseage); 
    //fixed area needs to enter parameters
    /* your code 
    
      House house1 = new House();  
    in this case there is no parameters added , why you need to add parameters because you called public House using parameters, it considerd as a parameterized constructor when creating an object, there for you need to provide values when calling from main function to fill the parameters. 
      
House class above mentioned constructor
public House (String houseName, int houseAge) {
                houseNAME = houseName; 
                houseAGE = houseAge; 
              }
    
    */
                
                System.out.println("House Name is : "+house1.getName());
                System.out.println("House Age is : "+house1.getAge());
                
                System.out.println("To change house name enter: 1 or else 0. ");// additional 
                int num=input.nextInt();
                
                if(num==1){
                    System.out.println("Enter new House Name: ");
                    String newhousename=input.next();
                    
                    house1.setName(newhousename);
                    System.out.println("New House Name is : "+house1.getName());
                }
                else if(num == 0 ){
                    return;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Invalid Value. ");
                }
            }         
        }
        
        
        
            class House {
              private String houseNAME; //
              private int houseAGE; //
            
              public House (String houseName, int houseAge) {
                houseNAME = houseName; //fixed area
                houseAGE = houseAge; //fixed area
              }
    
    /* your code
     public House (String houseName, int houseAge) {
        houseName = nameIn;
        houseAge = ageIn;
      }
    
    
    and in here above code there is no available variable or parameter  named nameIn and ageIn that can be equal to houseName,houseAge
    */
    
    
    
              public String getName() {
              return houseNAME;} //fixed area
            
              public int getAge() {
              return houseAGE;} //fixed area
    
    /* your code
    public int getAge() {
      return ageIn;
      }
    in the above code you have returned ageIn but there is no variable available there for compiler can't return a value. 
    in your code you have created variables 
    
    private String houseName;
    private int houseAge;
    
    you can return values that are stored in the variables.
    
    for get or return the name 
    public String getName() {
          return houseNAME;} here houseName is varible name.
     
    
    for return age
    public int getAge() {
          return houseAGE;} here houseAge is varible name.
    
    */
    
    
              public void setName (String houseName) {
              houseNAME = houseName; //fixed area
              }
    /* so in the above code you can equal the parameter value to the variable name since you are updating or setting a new name */
    
            }
```

Comment: Code-only answers like these (especially those that change a lot, as yours seems to) aren't really productive on this site. Our goal is to help the asker and all future visitors to this page, and providing the code with no context or prose explanation doesn't really teach anyone what went wrong, so much as give them the tools to pass their current homework assignment without any knowledge gained. Please consider adding a few paragraphs to explain what you changed, why you changed it, and how it solved the asker's problem.